# pyinstaller and problems with googleclinetapi

Tags: python, pyinstaller, google-api-client

I troied to build an .exe file with pyinstaller for my python code. There is a function in my code which works based on  googleapiclient.discovery import build. It finally built the .exe file. However when I run the .exe file, it gives this error:
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: vision  version: v1

(In a part of my program, I use build function from googleapiclient to build a serivce:
vservice = build('vision', 'v1', developerKey=APIKEY))

Above error is not shown when I directly run my program from terminal or from Jupyter notebook. What is the reason for this error that is generated only in the 'exe file from pyinstaller?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using drive and gmail api.
solved by downgrading the google-api-python-client version to 1.8.0

pip install google-api-python-client==1.8.0